# Use date on form to change records in subforms

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a form, essentially that is linked to a table called "master". One of the columns is "date" which is represented on the form as a dropbox.

On the same form, I have two subforms - one named fuel (feed from table "fueldip"), and the other named oil (feed from table "oildip"), both with fields also called "date".

In the Form, when I change the date value, I would like the subforms to display the record that match that date.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A few points. You say it is a "Linked" table... but not specifying what it is Linked to... i.e. if it is Linked to a SQL Server back I would suggest changing the name of the "master" table.

Second, it seems from your description that you have date fields in all three of your forms record sources... if you want the date to match the parent form always I would even question whether you need date fields in either of the subforms tables as this seems redundant... Why update the same date in three places when one would suffice?

But admittedly I am not aware of the scope of your application... maybe there is good reason to preserve this architecture.

To answer your question I would probably use VBA. I would use the parent form [Date] control on lost focus event. (I also suggest changing the name of the columns named "Date") something like this:

```
Private Sub Date_LostFocus()
    Me.fuel.Form.[Date] = Me.Date
    Me.fueldip.Form.[Date] = Me.Date
End Sub
```

It's untested but it should be close to what you although again I do suggest rethinking your structure.